# Primefaces Calendar Listener not affecting data to variable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, calendar

I have two `Datepicker`/`Calendar`(Primefaces) , what I want to do is when I'll click on the second Calendar I'll call a Listener that will caclulate the days between the two dates. So this is what I've did:

**Web Page**

```
<a:column span="4" >
            <a:label value="Begining Date" span="4"   required="true"  ></a:label>
            <a:column span="8">
                <p:calendar  id="idBegDate"  value="#{addController.enti.begDate}"
                             pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  label="Begining Date" 
                             readonlyInput="true" locale="fr" navigator="true"
                             required="true" >

                </p:calendar>

            </a:column>
        </a:column>

        <a:column span="4" >
            <a:label value="End Date" span="4"   required="true"  ></a:label>
            <a:column span="8">
                <p:calendar  id="idDateFin"  value="#{addController.enti.dateFinAbsAgt}"
                             pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  label="End Date" 
                             readonlyInput="true" locale="fr" navigator="true"
                             required="true" >
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{addController.doCalculate()}" update="jourCalendaire" />
                </p:calendar>

            </a:column>
        </a:column>
```

**Backing Bean**

```
public void doCalculate()
{
//..Some Stuffs
}
```

---

The problem is that when the listener is called it says that the `dateOfBegining` is `NULL` while it shouldn't be.

I found the solution to this issue by adding an empty `listener` to the `first calendar`:

```
public void emptyListener()
{

}
```

I think this is not logical, so I want to know why the webpage/backingBean had this behavior ? Is there a way in which I can use only the listener of the second calendar ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `p:ajax` of the second calendar, you need to add `process="@this idBegDate"` so JSF knows to take the value of `@this` (the second calendar) and `idBegDate` (the first calendar) and put it into your model object.

Nothing from the view will come back to the server unless you process it. Adding a `p:ajax` to the first calendar processed it for you.

Comment: This is working, can you please explain me why It doesn't affect it to the `backingbean` variable when I don't have `<p:ajax>` in the first date ?

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi read [process/update attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes). My short version is `process` attribute tells JSF what to _process_ from the view and updates the bean values bound to those components